# what does clear() do?

Tags: c++, g++

if I don't have istring.clear.() in my code, the output would be "nan%". everything works well and output is 60% if it's there. What does it really do there? why it makes a difference? (p.s my input is "y n y n y")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//inline function
inline ifstream& read(ifstream& is, string f_name);
//main function
int main ()
{
    string f_name=("dcl");
    ifstream readfile;
    read(readfile, f_name);
    string temp, word;
    istringstream istring;
    double counter=0.0, total=0.0;
    while(getline(readfile,temp))
    {
        istring.str(temp);
        while(istring>>word)
        {
            if(word=="y")
                ++counter;
            if(word=="n" || word=="y")
                ++total;
        }
        istring.clear();
    }
    double factor=counter/total*100;
    cout<<factor<<"%"<<endl;
    return 0;   
}

inline ifstream& read(ifstream& is, string f_name)
{
    is.close();
    is.clear();
    is.open(f_name.c_str());
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`clear()` resets the error flags on a stream (as you can read in the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/clear/)). If you use formatted extraction, then the error flag "fail" will be set if an extraction fails (e.g. if you're trying to read an integer and there isn't anything parsable). So if you're using the error state to terminate the loop, you have to make the stream usable again before going into the next loop.

In your particular case, though, your code is just poorly written and violates the "maximum locality principle". A saner version, that as a bonus doesn't require `clear()`, would be like this:

```
std::string temp;
while (std::getline(readfile, temp))
{
  std::istringstream iss(temp);
  std::string word;

  while (iss >> word)
  {
      std::cout << word << "_" << std::endl;
      if (word == "y") ++counter;
      if (word == "y") ++total;
  }
}
```

Some people would even write the outer loop as `for (std::string temp; std::getline(readfile, temp); ) { /* ... */ }`, though others consider this abuse.

Comment: maximum locality principle means to maximize the space?

Comment: so I don't really need that istring.clear() statement, right?

Comment: @ihm: No, it means to keep declarations of variables in as local a scope as possible. In your case, you don't need the string stream outside the loop, so you only *declare* (and thus initialize) it inside the loop. Don't be afraid to throw something away when you're done with it and get something new when you need it in C++ :-) And when you initialize a new stream, its error flags are automatically unset.

Comment: cool. it solved the problem. I think I need to keep every variable in the right scope and stop declare them here and there. is it right?

Comment: @ihm: It definitely a good idea to declare variables in their appropriate scope. It'll make the code a lot easier to read, to maintain and to refactor. Imagine you want to move a part of it around; that'd be way simpler if you have everything where it's needed.

Comment: as you can see my code format doesn't look good.how should I organize them and make them pretty?